# React Native animate view position based on flat list offset

Tags: react-native, animation

I want to animate a view's(say abcView) position based on main container flat list scroll offset. If the user scrolls down, abcView's position should move to bottom proportionately(vice versa when user scrolls back up). The position of abcView should change in proportion to the flatlist offset and not in one go. I want to use animated API but need ideas how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try below functional component

```
function SomeComponent() {
    const [scrollY] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

    const translateY = scrollY.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 150],
        outputRange: [0, 150],
        extrapolate: 'clamp',
        useNativeDriver: true,
    });
    return (
        <View>
            <Animated.FlatList 
                onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: scrollY } } }])}
            />
            <Animated.View
                style={{
                    transform: [{ translateY: translateY }],
                }}
            ></Animated.View>
        </View> 

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you need ideas, I think what you are looking for is the **parallax effect**. You can either go ahead building your own or you can search for such libraries e.g. [react-native-parallax-header](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-parallax-header)

Comment: you notice the floating action button (+ icon) in the link you gave. I want to animate Y position of that button with scroll.

Comment: So have you tried working on @Tuan's answer, i.e. moving Y position according to FlatList scroll?